# How to serialize an object instance which gets the data from 2 separate models using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

**Query** :

I have a GET request which gives the data from the 2 models (single_tracklog_object in View). However, when I serialize this object instance using the serializers  I am getting an empty data for devices as below.

```
{
    "lat": "51.0038",
    "lon": "8.0038",
    "speed": 50,
    "course": 5,
    "device": {} # this needs to be having a value but is empty.
}
```

I am not understanding why its happening. Please guide me on this.

**My Models** :

```
class Tracklogs(models.Model):
     tracklog_id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     device             = models.ForeignKey(Tracking_devices, related_name='tracklogs')    
     lat                = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
     lon                = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=False)

   .........

#timestamps

    tracker_datetime   = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = "tracker_datetime"



class Tracking_devices(models.Model):
     device_id          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     device_type        = models.ForeignKey(Device_type)

     user               = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)    
     name               = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     description        = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

**My View** :

```
serializer_class = ShowLocationInfoSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    # get the imei from the url
    imei = self.kwargs['imei']

    try:

        single_tracklog_object = Tracklogs.objects.filter(device__imei = imei).values('lat', 'lon','speed','course','device','device__name').latest()

        # Here its causing problem!!!
        serializer = self.serializer_class(single_tracklog_object)
        return Response(serializer.data)

     except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

**My Serializer**:

```
class Tracking_DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Tracking_devices
    fields =  ('name')

class ShowLocationInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lat = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    lon = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    speed = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    course = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
    device = Tracking_DeviceSerializer()


class Meta:
    model = Tracklogs
    fields = ('lat', 'lon', 'tracker_datetime', 'speed', 'course', 'device' )
```

Thanks in advance.